# How to check the health of a specific validator from another server/pc other than the validator itself (beyond watchtower)

Tags: validator

I want to monitor the voting validator (main server) from the non-voting validator (spare server running with an unfunded identity). I already use **solana-watchtower** from that server (as a service) to monitor the health of the voting validator and this info is used to send alert on telegram/discord and so on but, i would like to have the health info to trigger a bash script (for example delinquency status to trigger some commands) and no other output channels are apparently available with this tool. I thought to **gethealth** RPC command but it seems that i cannot pass parameters to specify which validator to monitor. What else could be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getHealth` endpoint gives the health information of the running validator, so you could send `getHealth` to your voting validator if it's running RPC, as long as you're sure to keep its RPC service private.

But even easier might be to modify `solana-watchtower` yourself. The source code exists at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/watchtower, and you can add a line after `notifier.send` to shell out to your bash script at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e9a6bb35e2636275137fc47837f5afce4dbcf630/watchtower/src/main.rs#L391 by doing something like:

```
use std::process::Command;

Command::new("bash my_script.sh")
    .spawn()
    .expect("command failed to start");
```